# Is there a way to see the history of questions protected by me or another user?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, profile-page, protected-questions

Having a record of all actions taken on a site, as is provided by the "activity" and "votes" tabs of our profile, comes in handy very often. Perhaps the most common case is being able to find a question I've interacted with in the past, to see if anything has changed about it.

This applies to questions a user has protected as much as anything else. Users are theoretically encouraged to unprotect questions when it's no longer necessary, as emphasized [in the latest blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/changes-and-guidelines-for-the-protected-question-status/), but in practice they often do not. In many cases it's hard to blame them: unless they specifically marked it as a favourite, the site doesn't keep any record of the question to allow them to find it again. We should help users more easily review their own protections in the future.

> [image]

For personal review, the votes tab is adequate, but there may also be value in displaying this publicly in the activity tab. There may be users with a history of repeatedly protecting questions over-eagerly. It would be useful to be able to review other users' protection histories to see if this is the case.

Even if this is not available to regular users, it may be helpful to moderators, unless their user activity views already allow them to filter down to see this.

Comment: Data explorer can help (e.g. [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/138825/questions-protected-a-user))

Comment: Data explorer is the only way (subject to delays).  The API has no provision for this.  You might make this a feature request.

Comment: Is this really a huge peril, though?  10 rep is an extremely low bar, and most questions are protected because there are a lot of looky-loos on the question, and one or two of them have posted comments as answers or even spam links.  I don't think twice about protecting such questions, and I don't recall ever reconsidering my decision to protect a question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, perhaps you should. Anecdotally, I have seen some first-time posts that brought new value to old questions (Don't have links at the moment).  SWAG that maybe 20% of first timers are a problem on these Q's and 20% have some real news to contribute -- We need to crunch some numbers (if possible for non-devs).  I'm not a fan of discouraging potential good contributors because a *different* minority is ill-mannered. ... ... Still, all that said, since this info can be had from SEDE and is low demand, I'd call this feature request a "Nice ta", not a priority.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not a *huge* one. When I posted the question, I was looking for if there is an existing page that can check on it but I didn't find yet. If there isn't, not a big deal for me :)

Comment: "it needs to be done only by the same person who protected it" is no longer true, now every 15K user can unprotect any protected question, even if protected by moderator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update July 2017:

I've gone ahead and written this up internally for review as one of [our features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291031/what-features-did-the-community-team-discuss-have-implemented-or-have-denied-l). While it's moving through the process, I'll change the tag to [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred).

---

I agree that this should be on the profile but at this time we're not exactly sure where.  I will say that I'm looking at it and hopefully will have something together in the next... well, you know the timeframe.

Ideally, I'd like to create a new tab on the profile page for "moderator actions" which will list all of your actions based on [moderator privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges?tab=moderation), I just need to determine what should be included on the tab.

Once I get that figured out and a possible design/mockup, then we can go forward with this. But it's definitely on my radar along with a few other things to correct issues with protected questions including [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274324/prevent-protecting-questions-under-certain-circumstances), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273882/show-10kers-a-larger-list-of-recently-protected-questions), and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269628/please-add-the-list-of-questions-un-protected-to-the-profile-page).

Just know that I'm reviewing it, so I'll [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) this for the time-being.

Comment: Any update on this?