# Please add the list of questions (un-)protected to the profile page

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, profile-page, protected-questions

Currently, the profile page does not show which questions one (un-)protected.

One [can get a list from SEDE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310574/3204551) (at most one week old, not containing deleted questions), but that's somewhat cumbersome.
I guess it should be the point eight under the votes tab, not number nine under the actions tab, though it doesn't matter that much.

Comment: Any value you see in these stats?

Comment: The same utility I see in being able to look at what I voted up, down, close, open, erased, or unerased. Finding things again for any unrelated reason (most of the time), or for correcting/reconsidering/reconfirming past actions.

Comment: Just to be clear: does the profile page not show questions that were protected but were later unprotected? (ie. (un-)protected?) Or does that mean something else?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ It doesn't even acknowledge that there is something like "protecting a question". Keeping (but marking as deleted?) any such action which was overturned (and not reinstated?) would just be a bonus.

Comment: Closing this as a dup of the other post, as they basically are asking for the same thing. I've written it up internally to see if we can get this implemented.