# Show 10kers a larger list of recently protected questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, 10k-tools, protected-questions

I recently reached 15k on Stack Overflow, and promptly went to check out my new privileges. Results:

- Questions protected: 0
- Questions unprotected: >10

Turns out, people protect things for *weird* reasons - sometimes no apparent reason at all. As described in [Changes and guidelines for the Protected Question status](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/changes-and-guidelines-for-the-protected-question-status/), I've been unprotecting these:

> **Do** *unprotect* questions that aren't currently attracting a lot of attention and don't have a *long* history of unproductive answers.

However, it's hard to find these bogus protections in a timely manner. The list in the 10k tools only shows the last 15 protections, which means I inevitably miss some when I'm not watching the list consistently (or go to sleep, a habit I need to shake anyway). I've been running SEDE queries to find these after the fact, but that only updates once a week.

Could we increase the maximum number of items shown in that list to at least 50 (probably with "show more" links to load more in increments of 10 or 25 or something)?

Additionally, it would be useful to see *who* protected a question - specifically, whether it was a community member or Community auto-protecting after answers were deleted.

Thoughts?

Comment: It would be useful to see who deleted or undeleted posts, too, but [that's a separate request](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248507/allow-to-filter-deleted-posts-by-source-of-deletion-in-the-10-k-tools-or-it-lea).

Comment: I agree. I don't have 15k yet on any site, but I have 10k privileges on Mathematics and have flagged some posts that were recently protected by a specific user. I am sure there were more, as that user had protect a lot of questions of the recent ones.

Comment: @Undo how you see [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/protected-questions)? Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8JLO.png), or like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAu6U.jpg)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not sure what you're asking, but https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ8Hn.png

Comment: Thanks, see the comments under bluefeet's answer, rene and me see a different thing which looks pretty bad. My guess is that the style resides in a mod-only file, hence moderators see this fine. (And the developers can't know it's borked)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of this morning, there is a new 10k tool under `/tools` that provides a list of protected questions.

The page is found under links at the bottom of the page, and it is similar to some of the other 10k tools in that you are presented with multiple tabs for filtering the data. You can filter the list of protected questions by:

- all - lists all protected questions
- month - questions protected in the last month
- week - questions protected this week
- day - questions protected in the past day

It also provides additional details on who protected the question, the total number of answers in the past 30 days, and the total number of deleted answers.  This should make it a bit easier to see what questions are being protected and allow a bit of review.

Comment: @bluefeet if [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8JLO.png) is what you see (I'm on 100% zoom, I dubble checked) then we declare this status-bydesign ... ;)

Comment: @rene I'm definitely not seeing that and I'm on 100% zoom.

Comment: @bluefeet it looks the same for me on Edge as well and on firefox it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA1Rk.png), slightly different

Comment: Hmm @rene I'm not seeing that in any browser and neither are others. I'll ask the dev to take a look though

Comment: Definitely some spacing issues ([see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYJxS.png)).

Comment: @rene yup, same here. bluefeet, can you please post a screenshot of what you see? Maybe devs got a different CSS or some other dev magic at work?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've asked a dev to take a look but it's the weekend where he is so it might not be looked at until Monday.

Comment: @bluefeet thanks, but you [said you see something else](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273882/show-10kers-a-larger-list-of-recently-protected-questions#comment931509_287081), so curious to see that. (i.e. how it's *supposed* to look like. :-))

Comment: Mine [looks pretty normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAu6U.jpg) @ShadowWizard

Answer (score 5):

The recently protected section could use some love.  Right now, it just lists them.  That makes it a bit awkward for users who do check on the posts to see what is going on.

The following columns should be in place:

- Title of question
- Age of question
- Number of answers
- Who protected
- When it was protected

If people want to get fancy, add a [sparkline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparkline) to those to show a histogram of the data:

- Reputation of users posting answers
- Score of answers