# Add some "action" indicator to the column headers on the new Protected Questions 10k tool to indicate they can be sorted

Tags: feature-request, design, 10k-tools

The 10k tools just got a [cool new feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273882/show-10kers-a-larger-list-of-recently-protected-questions), but it's obviously still a little rough around the edges.

One thing I would like to see is some visual indication that the column headers on the new [Protected Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/protected-questions) view (Stack Overflow link) are sortable on click.

At the very least, I'd like the cursor to change on hover. Ideally we'd see the standard downward-facing arrow off to the side of the header that would indicate it is sorted according to that column.

Some padding on the cells for readability's sake would work wonders, too.

Comment: It's still miles ahead of [NATO](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) (`<hr>` separators? Really?)

Comment: It'd be much more useful for it to be an overall sort rather than just sorting within a single page.