# Protected Questions table design is broken for non moderators

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, 10k-tools, protected-questions

This is how the [recently added](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/287081/152859) [Protected Questions](//meta.stackexchange.com/tools/protected-questions) page appears to me: (MSE, but same on SO)

> [image]

As [mentioned by a moderator on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273882/show-10kers-a-larger-list-of-recently-protected-questions/287081#comment931539_273882), moderator see it fine:

> [image]

Can the design please be fixed for non moderators? (I guess it was a moderator-only page, using some moderator-only CSS/JS.)

Comment: Yeah, the styles are defined in the moderator css file. Will move things around tomorrow.

Comment: @Oded thanks, and good luck with the fix! :)

Comment: Hopefully it won't break the moderator version ;)

Comment: @Oded knock knock.

Comment: Our LESS has been heavily refactored lately, trying to find the right file to update - got a designer on it. Patience is a virtue :P

Comment: @Oded huh, one of those sneaky bugs that appears small at first, then grow bigger? Well, patience is something not foreign to me. Thanks! ;)

Comment: More of a - "so... where is this supposed to go now? Look at all those new possible places...". Once we figure it out, should be quick enough to fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got some styles shuffled around different files, so the styling for the table should work for everyone, not just moderators.

With you in the next build.

Comment: Oded, how easy / difficult would be to extend this table with _unprotected_ events? (for the sake of completeness)

Comment: On the technical side - the work is very similar to what's already been done with protected events. Not sure about it being worth doing though.

Comment: thanks for explaining! Agree with you in that I also can't figure yet if it would be useful or not. Anyway, it is helpful to know that technically this is feasible, just in case